# Read from file with Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have some problems with reading from file.I think the best way to explain what's happening is to show you the code.

```
   File x = new File("D:\\player.txt");
   try {
        e = new Scanner(x);
        while (e.hasNext()) {

             playername = e.next();
             playerlevel = e.next();
             playerstrenght = e.next();
             playerdefense = e.next();
             playersoul = e.next();

        }
```

Comment: What are your problems? Please elaborate further... Are you getting an exception, an error log?

Comment: Please post the exact problem you're getting. If it is an exception post the stack trace.

Comment: @AliAlamiri   Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
 at Player.playerchose(Player.java:27)
 at Core.main(Core.java:10)

Comment: if playername, playerlevel, etc are int, float, whatever you could use nextInt() for int, nextFloat() for float and so on. And btw, before the catch, you need to call the close method for your scanner object : e.close() in your case. You could also get an error if you don't have those fields in your file. Good luck !

Comment: Thanks.The field are here.I'll try to close my Scanner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everytime you call `next()` you need to make sure, it has elements to read, in other words you need to call `hasNext()`. Here you are just calling `hasNext()` once and then calling next() multiple times. What if it had only one element and it entered while loop, but then for other `next()` call you will get error

```
 File x = new File("D:\\player.txt");
try {
    e = new Scanner(x);
    while (e.hasNext()){

     playername = e.next();
     if(e.hasNext()){
     playerlevel = e.next();
     }

     if(e.hasNext()){
     playerstrenght = e.next();
      }
     if(e.hasNext()){
        playerdefense = e.next();
      }
      if(e.hasNext()){
        playersoul = e.next();
      }

}
```

Above code is just to show you what you are doing wrong. It is very rough solution of the problem.

Comment: he does use hasNext()

Comment: @AliAlamiri not correctly

Comment: playername = e.next();
    e.hasNext();
    playerlevel = e.next();
    e.hasNext();
    playerstrenght = e.next();
    e.hasNext();
    playerdefense = e.next();
    e.hasNext();
    playersoul = e.next();
        
Like that? @AliAlamiri

Comment: @AliAlamiri Dude thanks a lot! Im new in java but I hope soon I'll get better.Im 12 years old actually.Again THANKS!